# How to use multiple graphics on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I have a `JButton` and when I click on this button it should draw a graph.

```
Peach p = new Peach();
MyGr Gr = new MyGr();

build = new JButton("Build graph");
        build.setBounds(320,550,100,20);
        build.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                add(Gr);
            }

        });

        add(build);

    add(p);

    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And I have two graphics objects:

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Peach extends JPanel {
......

}
```

And my graph:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyGr extends JPanel {

    int w = 200;
    int h = 425;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2.setColor(Color.black);

        Polygon p = new Polygon();

        for (int x = -3; x < 4; x++) {

            p.addPoint(w + 17 * x, h - 2* ((1) * x * x * x * x + 0 * x * x + (-1) * x * x + (5) * x - 10));
        }

        g2.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);


    }
}
```

Right now nothing happens

[image]

When I add content of `MyGr` to Peach class and use only Peach then it works fine, but I want to display a graph when I click on button

[image]

So, when I click this button, it should build a graph.
I don't understand why `add(Gr);` inside `actionPerfomed` doesn't work.

Comment: The best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: Side note: after adding a component (here `Gr`) to a container, you'll want to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container to lay out the new component and then have the container redraw itself and all its parts. Also you are using `setBounds` which suggests use of `null` layouts. If so, this is something that you really don't want to do.

Comment: Based on your images, it appears that you may be going about your program wrong. Rather than adding new components to the graph-drawing GUI you should instead consider adding Shape objects to the a collection held by the current drawing JPanel, drawing them within its paintComponent and then calling `repaint()` on it